# Show directories and files in wordpress uploads folder

Tags: php, wordpress

When I select media files for featured images from wordpress create or edit the post, Is there any way to show the list of folders in the uploads directory?

Comment: Uploads folder is organized by years and subfolder months. There is filter top-left to select month and year. Is that not good enough?

Comment: I have some custom directories in uploads.  I need those custom folders also to list in there.